# Delay in executing method after dispatch group operations are complete in iOS

Tags: ios, asynchronous, queue, grand-central-dispatch

I am calling a method after after the queues in my dispatch group complete executing. However, there is a significant delay in executing the final method even after all the queues have been executed. Can anyone explain any probable reasons?

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_group_async(group, queue,^{
     //some code             
}


dispatch_group_notify(group, queue,
    ^{
        [self allTasksDone];
    });
```

What I meant was that the method allTasksDone is executed after some delay even when the operation in the async queue has completed.

Comment: Please, add some code to your question. It's almost impossible to guess what you want.

Comment: How are you adding the delay? Are you using dispatch_after or performSelector?

Comment: No I havent added any kind of delay. I have added some code so it would be easier to guess what could be happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does `-allTasksDone` work?  If it's communicating with the user by updating user interface elements, it need to run on in the main thread's context, or else it'll appear that the UI elements in question are "delayed" -- they won't update until the main run loop happens to make them update.

Try this instead:

```
dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(),
^{
    [self allTasksDone];
});
```

As it is, you're running `-allTasksDone` on the default background queue, which doesn't play nice with AppKit or UIKit.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I dont have my mac with me at the moment but I will try this when I get back to work tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest an alternative approach although you can most certainly accomplish this using *dispatch groups*.

```
// Important note: This does not work with global queues, but you can use target queues to direct your custom queue to one of your global queues if you need priorities.
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.mycompany.myqueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);

dispatch_async(queue,^{
     //some code             
}

dispatch_barrier_async(queue,
    ^{
        // this executes when all previously dispatched blocks have finished.
        [self allTasksDone];
    });
```